# How can I get data which equals a specific user in my MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to show different information from the database on my website depending on which user is logged in. I have just begun with MVC (have done a couple of tutorials and can see information through my views on webpage.) Now I want to filter data on the user who is logged in. I am thinking a where clause somewhere. I am thinking in this controller where the context gets the data from db.

But how? Or is this the wrong place? Please tell me if you need some more info..

I am trying with 
    `db.Contacts.ToList().Where()`, but I don´t get access to UserName here..

```
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

// GET: 
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Contacts.ToList());
}
```

Comment: how does your table structure looks like ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does your Contacts class look like? Presumably there's a foreign key on it pointing to the user for whom the contacts belong to. Something like:

```
public class Contact
{
    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; } // the Id of the User the contact belongs to
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

You can then filter on that user id:

```
return View(db.Contacts.Where(c => c.UserId == CurrentUserId).ToList());
```

You can get the current user id by looking at the [User.Identity.Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property in your controller. Assuming when the user authenticated you stored their username

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    User current = db.Users.Single(u => u.Username == User.Identity.Name);

    return View(db.Contacts.Where(c => c.UserId == current.Id).ToList());
}
```

To make things easier, I put the CurrentUserId call in a base controller, so that any action can just reference CurrentUserId and be on its way.

Comment: I do basically the same except instead of putting the CurrentUserId in the base controller, I put it in a utility class which pulls from Session (it's a costly lookup in our system) or retrieves if missing from session. It's a bit of a performance boost for us, is reusable across multiple controllers and keeps them all a bit more clean.

Comment: I agree, I do the same thing with caching the current user. I like the CurrentUser property on my base controller, and use OnActionExecuting() to look up from cache/session. That way individual actions don't need to do anything special, they can just use CurrentUser. For unit testing, it lets me bypass Session (since OnActionExecuting() doesn't fire), and just set the CurrentUser property manually.